# Build a .dmg file from .py using pyinstaller on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, macos, pyinstaller

I have to build a python app for a MacOS user and I'm using Windows. I saw that using pyinstaller you can build .app files, but how do I do that on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

As [Pyinstaller's docs](https://pypi.org/project/PyInstaller/) states:

> PyInstaller is tested against Windows, Mac OS X, and GNU/Linux.
>   However, it is not a cross-compiler: to make a Windows app you run
>   PyInstaller in Windows; to make a GNU/Linux app you run it in
>   GNU/Linux, etc. PyInstaller has been used successfully with AIX,
>   Solaris, and FreeBSD, but is not tested against them.

This means you can't by only using Pyinstaller. You can try using something like a virtual machine, or containers, and use the common way (`pyinstaller <script>.py`) to do this

Comment: So what do I do?

Comment: You can try using Pyinstaller with a Virtual Machine, running MacOS inside it. I know Mac has some limitations, but i think you can manage to run it inside a Virtual Machine. Not sure how hard it is though, i never tried it.