# Is there any way to create .dmg python applications on a windows device?

Tags: python, windows, macos, bots

Long story short, I have made an automation script in python for a person who uses mac and I need to export the script into an application but .exe files don't work on mac and that's the method I know. What other things can I try?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560284/build-a-dmg-file-from-py-using-pyinstaller-on-windows

Comment: I have no idea what your question is getting at, but if you want to create a `.dmg` disk image on Windows, you can use 7-zip https://www.7-zip.org/